# Explicit Return Type of Lambda

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, c++11, visual-c++-2012

When I try and compile this code (VS2010) I am getting the following error:
`error C3499: a lambda that has been specified to have a void return type cannot return a value`

```
void DataFile::removeComments()
{
  string::const_iterator start, end;
  boost::regex expression("^\\s?#");
  boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
  boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
  // Look for lines that either start with a hash (#)
  // or have nothing but white-space preceeding the hash symbol
  remove_if(rawLines.begin(), rawLines.end(), [&expression, &start, &end, &what, &flags](const string& line)
  {
    start = line.begin();
    end = line.end();
    bool temp = boost::regex_search(start, end, what, expression, flags);
    return temp;
  });
}
```

How did I specify that the lambda has a 'void' return type. More-over, how do I specify that the lambda has 'bool' return type?

**UPDATE**

The following compiles. Can someone please tell me why that compiles and the other does not?

```
void DataFile::removeComments()
{
  boost::regex expression("^(\\s+)?#");
  boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
  boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
  // Look for lines that either start with a hash (#)
  // or have nothing but white-space preceeding the hash symbol
  rawLines.erase(remove_if(rawLines.begin(), rawLines.end(), [&expression, &what, &flags](const string& line)
  { return boost::regex_search(line.begin(), line.end(), what, expression, flags); }));
}
```

Comment: You can explicitly specify it with `->`, e.g. `[&](double d) -> double { //...`

Comment: I'd advise you to just implicitly capture the variables you need (only `[&]...`), as what you currently have is needlessly verbose.

Comment: @Xeo can you tell me why its verbose? I need what, expression and flags in the lambda and that is what I have captured. What mroe could I cut out?

Comment: `[&expression, &start, &end, &what, &flags]...` (yours) vs `[&]...` (mine). Now tell me whose is more verbose. ;) `[&]` tells the lambda to capture everything that you use inside the lambda body, by reference. It's called a "capture default". The other one is `[=]` and will capture by copy.

Comment: @Xeo, Effective Modern C++, Item 31, recommends capturing explicitly, to avoid dangling references. I've been bitten by that a few times myself as punishment for being laz... er, concise. :-)

Comment: @Emile: That only matters for lambdas that outlive the current scope in some form or other, really, which is certainly not the case here.

Comment: By the way, the constraints are reduced on deduced return-type lambdas in C++14.  Return types can be deduced for lambdas with more than one statement in the body, and as long as the expression of each return statement has the same type, you can now have a deduced return type with multiple return statements.

Comment: Also see [Is my book's discussion of lamba return types wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14738335), [When can we omit the return type in a C++11 lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28955478), [Why do lambda functions drop deduced return type reference by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41534031) and [Explicit Return Type of Lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9620098).

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the return type of a lambda by using `-> Type` after the arguments list:

```
[]() -> Type { }
```

However, if a lambda has one statement and that statement is a return statement (and it returns an expression), the compiler can deduce the return type from the type of that one returned expression. You have multiple statements in your lambda, so it doesn't deduce the type.

Comment: the compiler can do that, but the standard forbids it to do that.

Comment: -1: This is not a compiler bug. The standard is very clear on this: section 5.1.2, paragraph 4 lays out how the deduction is made and under what conditions it is.

Comment: While it is not allowed according to the latest draft I could find it looks like it is actually allowed in the final specs going by the comment for this patch http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2011-08/msg01901.html. Anyone has the final spec to verify?

Comment: I've used lambda expressions extensively and not once did I explicitly state the return type.  The deduction of the return type (at least under VS2012 & VS2013) works flawlessly even if there's more than one return statement in the lambda expression. Of course, the various return statements need to match within the same lambda expression.  E.g. a statement such as "auto f = [](int i) { if(i > 5) return true; return false; };" compiles with no problem and if you call "auto b = f(10);" b will be of type bool and of course be true;

Comment: `return nullptr;` can throw a wrench in the type deduction, even though it's valid as whatever pointer type is otherwise returned.

Comment: `return ptr`; can also throw a wrench in type deduction if `const` is involved.

Answer (score 24):

The return type of a lambda (in C++11) can be deduced, but *only* when there is exactly one statement, and that statement is a `return` statement that returns an expression (an initializer list is not an expression, for example). If you have a multi-statement lambda, then the return type is assumed to be void.

Therefore, you should do this:

```
  remove_if(rawLines.begin(), rawLines.end(), [&expression, &start, &end, &what, &flags](const string& line) -> bool
  {
    start = line.begin();
    end = line.end();
    bool temp = boost::regex_search(start, end, what, expression, flags);
    return temp;
  })
```

But really, your second expression is a lot more readable.

Comment: Nice example; nitpick: Is your function call missing `);` at the end?

Answer (score 12):

You can have more than one statement when still return:

```
[]() -> your_type {return (
        your_statement,
        even_more_statement = just_add_comma,
        return_value);}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/#comma

Comment: comma is a revolting operator. its confuses people who aren't aware of its existence or precedence level. there is never a valid use either imo. it can always be avoided with more functions or otherwise better organised code.

Comment: @jheriko agree, the existence of my answer is only for those who really wants a independent one-liner solution XD (it's still one line, right?). The comma is really not noticeable, and no one would ever put the whole main method in this form.

Comment: sure, you are certainly giving a valid answer, i am just not a fan of ever doing anything to encourage or even demonstrate bad practice. once people learn that comma is an operator its a countdown until they start abusing it and a longer one until they learn better. :)

Comment: @jheriko I've seen it put to an interesting use in a member initialisation list once, but that was just for messing around, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Ah, but what reader did not at least first look to see if the comma operator was something you could overload.  Now what great evil would that be?