# Is my book's discussion of lambda return types wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, llvm, clang

My book says this:

> Lambdas with function bodies that contain anything other than a single return statement that do not specify a return type return void.

but this:

```
auto f = []{
  int i=0; i++;
  return std::string("foo");
};
std::cout << f() << std::endl;
```

actually compiles and prints out "foo", but that lambda expr has more than just a single return statement so it should return void, because it does not manually specify "-> std::string" as a return type.

What's going on here?

I'm using Apple's compiler in the latest Xcode 4.6, based on Clang 3.2 it seems:

clang --version

Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: This example has only a single `return` statement.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: It contains several statements besides the single return statement, however.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @GManNickG updated with compiler info

Comment: Short answer: The book is correct and your compiler is wrong.  (Long answers already provided by BenVoigt and dribeas.)

Comment: @BenVoigt: But those statements are, in essence, a nop. I wonder if that makes a difference to this *particular* implementation. I don't have easy access to a compiler right this instant to check.

Comment: @NikBougalis: It would be a disaster if compilers were allowed to determine a return type, because code might compile for one implementation and fail on another.  That's why the Standard spells out *exactly* how types are determined, and the implementation must use that type, even if it's "smart enough" to figure out another possibly intended meaning.

Comment: I don't disagree - clearly this particular implementation is not standards-compliant. I'm just wondering out loud whether the compiler "optimizes" the lambda first and deduces the type by looking at that optimized code.

Comment: Also see [Is my book's discussion of lamba return types wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14738335), [When can we omit the return type in a C++11 lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28955478), [Why do lambda functions drop deduced return type reference by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41534031) and [Explicit Return Type of Lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9620098).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book accurately reflects the rules in draft n3290 of the Standard.  Perhaps your compiler implemented a different draft.

In section 5.1.2p4, the draft reads

> If a *lambda-expression* does not include a *trailing-return-type*, it is
>   as if the *trailing-return-type* denotes the following type:
>
> - if the *compound-statement* is of the form
>       `{` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub> `return` *expression* `;` `}`
>     the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, and function-to-pointer conversion;
> - otherwise, void.

The syntactic construct *attribute-specifier-seq* may be `alignas` or the double-bracketed attributes.  Not variable declarations.

Draft n3485, which followed publication of C++11 (i.e. it is work in progress toward C++1y), contains the same wording.  I don't know if there was a different rule in some draft earlier than n3290.

Comment: Also there is a proposition to eliminate the requirement for only one statement for return-type deduction in the future.

Comment: It's not from a different version of the spec, it's a compiler extension.

Answer (score 3):

If you use popular compilers (gcc, Visual Studio), you usually don't need to specify return type as long as the compiler is able to determine it unambiguously - like in your example.

The following example shows a lambda, which requires explicit return type information:

```
auto lambda = [](bool b) -> float
    { 
        if (b) 
            return 5.0f; 
        else 
            return 6.0; 
    };
```

I asked Bjarne Stroustrup regarding this matter, his comment:

`I do not know if C++11 allows the deduction of the return type is there are several return statements with identical return type. If not, that's planned for C++14.`

Comment: According to the standard even the lambda in the original question requires the return type.

Comment: Indeed, but both Visual Studio and GCC compiles the original code without warnings. It's quite logical - in most situations compiler is able to clearly determine the return type - even, if the lambda's body is not of the form return sth. I sent an email to Bjarne Stroustrup about this matter, if he replies, I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @Spook : Compiling without warnings doesn't mean much – if they don't implement this extension, then you're merely invoking UB, which does not require a warning.

Comment: Standard speaks nothing of undefined behavior here. Note, that we're talking about return type, what affects the whole compilation process. Undefined behavior would require an 'undefined type', which would pass through all assignment-type checks, parameter-pass checks etc. In this particular case, if it compiles, one should rather assume, that compiler implements the extended syntax rather than undefined behavior will occur.

Comment: @Spook : You're right, I was erroneously thinking of the reverse scenario of having no return statement in a function with a non-void return type. Apologies for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what to make from the quote in the question, but here is what the C++11 standard says about lambdas without declarator or return type:

> If a lambda-expression does not include a lambda-declarator, it is as
> if the lambda-declarator were (). If a lambda-expression does not
> include a trailing-return-type, it is as if the trailing-return-type
> denotes the following type (5.1.2p4):
>
> — if the compound-statement is of the form
> { attribute-specifier-seqopt return expression ; } the type of the
> returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1),
> array-to-pointer conversion (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion
> (4.3);
>
> — otherwise, void.

Comment: That means in fact that the lambda may contain nothing but a return statement. The code of the OP is ill-formed - attempting to return a value from a void lambda.

Comment: @JoergB: Not really, it means that the return type will be `void` if there is anything other than a single return statement. But the lambda can have as much code as you want. That is, this is a valid lambda: `[](int i){std::cout << i; std::cout << i*i; .... somemorecode(); }`

Comment: The OP lambda is ill-formed not because it doesn't have a return type, but because of 6.6.3 "A return statement with an expression of non-void type can be used only in functions returning a value."

Comment: @David Rodriguez: No. As quoted, it states that the entire compound-statement that makes up the body of the lambda, must be a single return statement.

Comment: @aschepler: I did not even state that the lambda in the OP is ill-formed (which it is). The lambda is ill-formed because of the combination of lack of return type (which makes it yield `void`) together with the return statement that returns a value. Yes. So?

Comment: @David Rodriguez: ah, now I see. I did not spell out that I meant "... in order to have a deduced, non-void return type."

Comment: @JoergB: The absence of the trailing-return-type means one of two things: it is a single return statement, or there is an implicit `->void`. The *otherwise* includes any body that contains more than one statement, and it only states what the trailing-return-type means. It is perfectly fine to have a lambda without return type, with multiple statements as long as it does not return anything (to conform to the implicit `void` return type)

Comment: I think we misunderstood the "not really", and David is pointing out that JoergB's first comment would be more accurate as "That means in fact that the lambda should contain nothing but a return statement, if you want the compiler to deduce a type other than `void`."

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Ok, but both Visual Studio and GCC accepts more complicated lambdas (eg. `[](bool b){if (b) return 1; else return 2;}`) without trailing return type and they deduce returned value's type correctly. Does it mean, that VS and GCC does not follow C++11 stanard?

Comment: @Spook: They don't conform to the standard, or they can call that an *extension* and get away with it :)

Comment: Sure, but it seems, that all of them (or at least most of them) does that. It's weird, this restriction seems to be unnecessary - and IMO should be left implementation-specific (eg. in case of multiple statements). Compilers obviously can deduce the returned type in many situations, why does the standard restrict that to a single return statement?

Comment: @Spook: The Standard has to pick some single clearly understood rule, so that all implementations treat the same confirming code the same way.  Even if the current wording isn't particularly logical, just allowing compilers to each use their own algorithms would be much worse.

Comment: @aschepler: Implementations are free to allow for extensions that are not in the language. Nothing inhibited GCC from implementing VLA, which are not in the standard. Sun CC will open a .cpp file to try to find a template definition if the .h contains the template declaration. VS has stricter semantics to `volatile`... Whether you should code to make use of the extensions or the standard is a different question, and if you need portability you should avoid all extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Clang implements the proposed resolution to [C++ core issue 975](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#975). That allows an arbitrary body for a lambda, with any number of return statements, and deduces the return value from the returned expression under the proviso that they must all produce the same type.

In C++14, this support is generalized further by [N3638](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3638.html), which was voted into the working draft for the standard at the Bristol meeting of WG21.

Answer (score 0):

Draft n3485 indicates that if the compiler can unambiguously determine the return type it will allow for the lambda to not specify it.

Comment: I just downloaded it from https://github.com/cplusplus/draft and the wording hasn't changed.

Comment: I'm reading this draft now and I cannot find the informations you're citing. Can you provide page or section number?

Comment: See section 5.1.2.4. Did I misunderstand what the text says, perhaps?

Comment: Can you cite the fragment? I found only the text cited by DavidRodriguez and it states, that compiler may deduce the returned type *only if* the lambda's body is a single return statement (otherwise, void return type is assumed).