# Why do lambda functions drop deduced return type reference by default?

Tags: c++, lambda, clang, c++14, auto

In C++14, why do lambda functions with a deduced return type drop references from the return type by default? IIUC, since C++14 lambda functions with a deduced return type (without an explicit trailing return type) have a return type of `auto`, which drops references (among other things).

Why was this decision made? It seems to me like a gotcha to remove a reference when that's what your return statement returns.

This behavior caused the following nasty bug for me:

```
class Int {
public:
   Int(int i) : m_int{i} {}
   int m_int;
};

class C {
public:
    C(Int obj) : m_obj{obj} {}
    const auto& getObj() { return m_obj; }
    Int m_obj;
};

class D {
public:
    D(std::function<const Int&()> f) : m_f{f} {}
    std::function<const Int&()> m_f;
};

Int myint{5};
C c{myint};
D d{ [&c](){ return c.getObj(); } } // The deduced return type of the lambda is Int (with no reference)
const Int& myref = d.m_f(); // Instead of referencing myint, myref is a dangling reference; d.m_f() returned a copy of myint, which is subsequently destroyed.
```

Specifying the desired return type when initializing `d` resolves the issue:

```
D d{ [&c]() -> const Int& { return c.getObj(); } }
```

Interestingly, even if the `auto` return type deduction makes sense, isn't it a bug that `std::function<const Int&>` gets happily initialized with a function that returns a non-reference? I see this also by writing explicitly:

```
D d{ [&c]() -> Int { return c.getObj(); } }
```

which compiles without a problem. (on `Xcode 8`, `clang 8.0.0`)

Comment: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/i1EFa0F9k6sPUFjv your code can't be compiled. your lambda return type is void. Please post an MVCE.

Comment: @Danh It compiles for me if you use `D d{ [&c]() -> const Int& { c.getObj(); } }` in the last but one line

Comment: @volatilevar _warning: control reaches end of non-void lambda [-Wreturn-type]_ Undefined behavior for that case http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1fle9YwdtjNueOAA

Comment: @Danh I ignored warnings :) nvm

Comment: @volatilevar Even if you ignore the warnings, clang++ report that _Illegal instruction_

Comment: @Danh I realized I was using gcc...

Comment: The implied return type is `auto`, and `auto` works just like template argument deduction. If you want decltype semantics, say `-> decltype(auto)`.

Comment: @Danh Was just missing a return, compiles now

Comment: @KerrekSB This doesn't really answer the question, though. Does it really make sense for a lambda function which returns a reference to remove that reference, *by default*?

Comment: @Danra: That's a misconception due to sloppy language. Functions never "return references", they always return *values*, and values are never references. The only thing that the function return type ref qualification affects is the value category of the return value.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's the first time I've heard that. (functions never returns references, just values with a category of reference). I've no doubt you're correct, but I've never heard or read this in any talk/article by any of the gurus. It's very common to mention functions which return references, and it is still counter-intuitive, to my mind, that the reference category is dropped from lambdas in this way.

Comment: @Danra: The type system in C++ serves multiple purposes. Reference do what you think they do when applied to *variables*. But references are also used to communicate the value categories of values, namely in the form of declared function return types, in casts, and in `decltype`. Lots of things in C++ do unfortunately play several different roles in different contexts. It's important to stay alert and not get confused :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132631/discussion-between-danra-and-kerrek-sb).

Comment: Opened a separate question for the second part of the original one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549632/why-can-stdfunction-be-constructed-with-a-lambda-with-a-different-return-type

Comment: *"... which compiles without a problem. (on Xcode 8, clang 8.0.0)"* - I believe SunCC 12.5 will provide an error.

Comment: Also see [Is my book's discussion of lamba return types wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14738335), [When can we omit the return type in a C++11 lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28955478), [Why do lambda functions drop deduced return type reference by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41534031) and [Explicit Return Type of Lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9620098).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the place you are stumbling is actually with the expression `c.getObj()` in the line `return c.getObj();`.

You think the expression `c.getObj()` has type `const Int&`.  However that is not true; expressions never have reference type. As noted by Kerrek SB in comments, we sometimes talk about expressions as if they had reference type, as a shortcut to save on verbosity, but that leads to misconceptions so I think it is important to understand what is really going on.

The use of a reference type in a declaration (including as a return type as in `getObj`'s declaration) affects how the thing being declared is initialized,  but once it is initialized, there is no longer any evidence that it was originally a reference.

Here is a simpler example:

```
int a; int &b = a;  // 1
```

versus

```
int b; int &a = b;  // 2
```

These two codes are exactly identical <sup>(except for the result of `decltype(a)` or `decltype(b)` which is a bit of a hack to the system)</sup>.   In both cases the expressions `a` and `b` both have type `int` and value category "lvalue" and denote the same object.  It's not the case that `a` is the "real object" and `b` is some sort of disguised pointer to `a`.  They are both on equal footing. It's one object with two names.

Going back to your code now: the expression `c.getObj()` has exactly the same behaviour as `c.m_obj`, apart from access rights.   The type is `Int` and the value category is "lvalue".  The `&` in the return type of `getObj()` only dictates that this is an lvalue and it will also designate an object that already existed (approximately speaking).

So the deduced return type from `return c.getObj();` is the same as it would be for `return c.m_obj;` , which -- to be compatible with template type deduction, as mentioned elsewhere -- is not a reference type.

NB. If you understood this post you will also understand why I don't like the pedagogy of "references" being taught as "disguised pointers that auto dereference", which is somewhere between wrong and dangerous.

Comment: Great answer. Though, I wonder, why was the decision made to return `auto` rather than `decltype(auto)`? The latter would "forward" the reference-ness, applying the same initialization method to the return type of the lambda. To me, this would make more sense for the lambda return type deduction (even if it is incompatible with templates type deduction). Is it because `decltype(auto)` is a "hack", as you mention? In what way is it a hack?

Comment: @Danra I can't answer that authoritatively but I think it would make it too easy to accidentally have a lambda returning a dangling reference.  `decltype` gets information that's outside the normal type system for expressions which is why I called it a hack . But it is too useful in template metaprogramming to go without (sort of like the preprocessor!)

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts on this part? "Interestingly, even if the auto return type deduction makes sense, isn't it a bug that std::function<const Int&> gets happily initialized with a function that returns a non-reference? " (other than what @skypjack already mentioned in his answer)

Comment: @Danra that's outside scope of this question I think... comments aren't for extended discussion.  Maybe you could look for another question specifically about that `std::function` issue (or post one if you can't find one)

Comment: Opened as a separate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549632/why-can-stdfunction-be-constructed-with-a-lambda-with-a-different-return-type

Comment: Always hated references being taught like that, but could never really come up with a decent reason why, beyond philosophical/abstract OCD. Thanks for this much better ammo!

Comment: // Unfortunately, there are so many abstraction leaks in C++ that this does break down a bit under some circumstances, e.g. reference members, & [reference capture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53416206/560648) (despite compiler bugs that fit this more pure interpretation that's backed up by the rules of expressions)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit regarding reference members; I assume you're talking about the case of `int a; int &b = a;` in the class definition. I think the abstraction holds for a default-constructed instance; but obviously if the instance is constructed in such a way that the *brace-or-equal-initializer* is not used (e.g. copy-construction) then the behaviour would differ, since `b` is bound to some other object instead of `a`.

Comment: @M.M Not quite, I was thinking more of reference members that refer to things totally external to the object. In that sense, it's much easier to consider them to be pointer-like objects in their own right rather than alternative names for the referent. The semantics you've laid out aren't quite broken by that but it does muddy the waters a bit. The reference capture is a more pertinent example though I'd say.

Answer (score 4):

The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#5) (at least, the working draft) already gives you hints about what's happening and how to solve it:

> The lambda return type is `auto`, which is replaced by the type specified by the trailing-return-type if provided and/or deduced from return statements as described in [dcl.spec.auto]. [ Example:

```
    auto x1 = [](int i){ return i; }; // OK: return type is int
    auto x2 = []{ return { 1, 2 }; }; // error: deducing return type from braced-init-list int j;
    auto x3 = []()->auto&& { return j; }; // OK: return type is int&
```

> — end example ]

Consider now the following template function:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T t) {}

// ....

int x = 42;
f(x);
```

What's `t` in `f`, a copy of `x` or a reference to it?
What happens if we change the function as it follows?

```
template<typename T>
void f(T &t) {}
```

The same applies more or less to the deduced return type of a lambda: if you want a reference, you must be explicit about that.

> Why was this decision made? It seems to me like a gotcha to remove a reference when that's what your return statement returns.

The choice is consistent with how templates work since the beginning.
I would be surprised of the opposite instead.
Return type is deduced as well as the template parameter and it's a pretty good decision not to define different set of rules for them (at least from my point of view).

---

That said, to solve your problem you have several alternatives:

1. ```
   [&c]()->auto&&{ return c.getObj(); }
   ```
2. ```
   [&c]()->auto&{ return c.getObj(); }
   ```
3. ```
   [&c]()->decltype(c.getObj())&{ return c.getObj(); }
   ```
4. ```
   [&c]()->decltype(c.getObj())&&{ return c.getObj(); }
   ```
5. ```
   [&c]()->decltype(auto){ return c.getObj(); }
   ```
6. ```
   [&c]()->const Int &{ return c.getObj(); }
   ```
7. ```
   ...
   ```

Some of them are crazy, some of them are quite clear, all of them should work.
If the intended behavior is to return a reference, probably to be explicit about that is the best choice:

```
[&c]()->auto&{ return c.getObj(); }
```

Anyway, this is mostly opinion-based, so feel free to pick your preferred alternative up and use it.

---

> Interestingly, even if the auto return type deduction makes sense, isn't it a bug that std::function gets happily initialized with a function that returns a non-reference?

Let's consider the code below (no reason to call in a `std::function` right now):

```
int f() { return 0; }
const int & g() { return f(); }
int main() { const int &x = g(); }
```

It gives you a few warnings but it compiles.
The reason is that a temporary is created from an rvalue and a temporary can bind to a const reference, so I'd say it's *legal* from the point of view of the standard.
The fact that it will explode at runtime is another problem.

Something similar happens when using a `std:: function`.
Anyway it's an abstraction over a generic callable object, so do not expect the same warnings.

Comment: Interesting. In your example, what if you declared `const int& y = x` instead, and then called `f(y)`? Would that still derive T as an int value rather than a reference?

Comment: [You can easily test it for yourself](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NpTyNXfAdNb2S7BQ).

Comment: Thanks. That helps. What about this part? " isn't it a bug that std::function<const Int&> gets happily initialized with a function that returns a non-reference? "

Comment: @Danra The language doesn't forbid you to do this: `int & f() { int x; return x; }`. In your case, returned value is a temporary and it can bind to a const reference, so it's perfectly fine. The fact that it will explode at runtime is a problem of yours. ;-)

Comment: That's not the issue. In the original code, as well in the case that I specify explicitly that the return type is by value (see end of question), the `std::function<const Int&()>` member still gets happily initialized with the lambda.

Comment: @Danra As I said, [this compiles as well](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/usxoU5j5NQgN4dq8). Let me integrate the answer.

Comment: I see what you meant now. But the code example you attached does generate a warning. It seems crazy to me that constructing an `std::function` with one return type from a lambda with a different return type works with no warning - at least in the return by reference vs. return by value case.

Comment: @Danra Added an answer to your second question.