# Why can std::function be constructed with a lambda with a different return type?

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

The following [compiles fine](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aO3eLLNUYZ3ucxcx):

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::function<const int&()> f = []() -> int {return 1;};
    const int& r = f(); // r is a dangling reference
    return 0;
}
```

How come it's possible to set an `std::function` with a `const int&` return type to a lambda with an `int` return type? Allowing this sort of cast to happen implicitly and with no warning is a gotcha IMHO.

Comment: Because a const reference can bind to a temporary.  It's not a problem with `std::function` itself. You'd get the same net effect with good old functions. *That* part of the language isn't going anywhere any time soon.

Comment: But the destructor of the returned temporary gets called. Demonstrated here http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nSzeMfQM0Jpz9xbW

Comment: And? C++ never protected you from shooting yourself in the foot. Compilers may be nice and emit warnings, but this is still a valid program from a pure C++ perspective. And this is here to stay because binding a temporary to a reference can prolong the lifetime of a temporary under certain circumstances. And **that** is very useful.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, though. The fact that a const reference can bind to a temporary doesn't directly derive that an std::function with a const reference return type can be constructed from a lambda with a value return type.

Comment: But it does. Because a `std::function` is designed to allow any valid conversions to occur. And over-complicating it for corner cases that programmers should be aware of is just pointless IMO.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: is it correct to interpret that the std::function is constructed in such a way, that when it is called, it passes the arguments from outside to whatever callable it was constructed with, and then passes on the return? So it's more like a wrapper and just keep the callable inside (a possible implementation could be the function pointer?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct a `std::function` with any object which is callable with the relevant arguments and whose return value is implicitly convertible to the `std::function` return. `int` is implicitly convertible to `const int&`, so the rules are met.

A compiler could feel free to warn about this, but it seems like a lot of work for a particularly corner-y corner case.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually not that corner-y, since it's easy (at least, was for me) to make the mistake of assuming that the deduced return type of a lambda returning a const reference is also a const reference, which is false; it is just a value. So this is a bug I actually ran into due to not understanding the return type deduction of lambdas well enough (if you're curious, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534031/why-do-lambda-functions-drop-deduced-return-type-reference-by-default )

Comment: Warning that a reference return is bound to a temporary seems quite worthwhile and in fact is implemented in most major compilers. The problem here is that the broken return happens in a system header where warnings are suppressed. Also, there's an [LWG issue](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2813) requesting a tweak to `std::function` to make OP's code not compile.