# How to return const reference to vector item from a mocked method?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am writing googletest/googlemock-based unit tests for a class using a database object as a dependency, so I decided to mock the database. It provides read-only access to items of type `Entry` based on an index:

```
struct Entry {
    int x, y;
};

class DbIface {
public:
    virtual ~DbIface() {}
    virtual int count() const = 0;
    virtual const Entry& entry(const int idx) const = 0;
};

class DbMock : public DbIface {
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(count, int());
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(entry, const Entry&(const int idx));
};
```

I want to specify some predefined data for the test and make the mock return that:

```
const std::vector<Entry> TEST_DATA = { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 } };
DbMock mock;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, count).WillOnce(Return(TEST_DATA.size()));
EXPECT_CALL(mock, entry).WillOnce(Invoke([](int i) { return TEST_DATA.at(i); }));
```

However, I am getting an error on the last `EXPECT_CALL`:

> warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary

I expect the GMock-generated wrapper makes a copy from the reference returned by the lambda somewhere along the way, but it's difficult to follow in that mess of code. In any case, how do I achieve what I need without changing the interface?

Comment: Never used this but according to the docs there should probably be a `ReturnRef` in there somewhere, e.g. wrapping `Invoke`?

Comment: It doesn't work that way, ReturnRef(Invoke([]...)) would mean "return reference to the thing returned by Invoke()", which is some GMock internal type. Anyway, I found the cause of my problem, the return type of the lambda is actually deduced to be non-reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534031/why-do-lambda-functions-drop-deduced-return-type-reference-by-default

Comment: Cool. Yeah, was just a stab in the dark.

Answer (score 4):

As clarified by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534031/why-do-lambda-functions-drop-deduced-return-type-reference-by-default), the type of the `TEST_DATA.at(i)` expression is `Entry`, not `const Entry&`, so the lambda has its return type deduced to be non-reference, causing the problem.

This is fixed by explicitly stating the return type of the lambda:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, entry).WillOnce(Invoke([](int i) -> const Entry& { return TEST_DATA.at(i); }));
```

Comment: Oof, that would have taken me a while.