# Reason for failed Cppcheck "Reference to auto variable returned"?

Tags: c++, qt, cppcheck

I see the following `Cppcheck`, but do not understand why I am getting it:

`directoryutils.cpp 173 error   returnReference false   Reference to auto variable returned.`

Neither I understand why an `auto` variable would be returned, nor the "reference part". Is that a false positive?

header: `static const FilePerApplication &applicationDataDirectoryMapWithoutCurrentVersion();`

```
const CDirectoryUtils::FilePerApplication &CDirectoryUtils::applicationDataDirectoryMapWithoutCurrentVersion()
{
  static const FilePerApplication dirs = [ = ] {
      FilePerApplication directories;
      for (const QFileInfo &info : CDirectoryUtils::applicationDataDirectories())
      {
        .... fill in data ....
        directories.insert(info.filePath(), appInfo);
      }
      return directories; // LINE 173 why auto???
  }();

  return dirs;
}
```

1. Remark: `using FilePerApplication = QMap<QString, CApplicationInfo>;`
2. Remark: Also giving it an explicit return type `-> FilePerApplication` like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620143/356726 does not silence the check error

Comment: Show the declaration of the function in which this code is located. What's its return type?

Comment: updated as requested

Comment: "why an auto variable would be returned", because `directories` is a local object. I don't understand the "reference part" either. The return type of the lambda should be `FilePerApplication`, it seems Cppcheck thinks it's `FilePerApplication&`.

Comment: Generally, cppcheck doesn't do very well with lambdas. You can expect these types of false positives. The `auto` here means the variable has automatic storage. If I had to wildly guess, the reference comes from the method's signature... it just doesn't parse the lambda and thinks the return statement belongs to the method....

Comment: The current head of Cppcheck does not report anything with the sample code. But it could still be there and the code is not enough to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

The comment in [Reason for failed Cppcheck "Reference to auto variable returned"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635959/reason-for-failed-cppcheck-reference-to-auto-variable-returned#comment90241492_51635959) is most likely correct that it is about "automatic storage" and also it being a false positive related to incorrect handling of the lambda.

This error appeared in Cppcheck 1.48 and was fixed in version 1.54.